# CreateView - validate form and default fields

Tags: django, create-view

I'm trying to create new element using CreateView, and automatic generated form.

```
class OrderSelected(CreateView):
    model = Wynajem
    template_name = "order_room.html"
    success_url = '/my_orders/'
```

How to add default value to several Wynajem's fields and check if other fields send by post method are ok?

---

There's another problem.
Default value is argument in url:

```
url(r'^order/(?P<room>\d+)/$', login_required(OrderSelected.as_view()), name='order')
```

I want to set one field with room value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Default values:

Provide a `get_initial` method which returns a dictionary mapping fields to their default values.

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    # ...
    def get_initial(self):
        return { 'some_field': 'some_default_value' }
```

### Check fields in post:

This is what the forms framework is for (handling validation) - modify your form, or subclass it and do the modifications necessary before providing it to your class.

```
class MyForm(FormToSubclass):
   def clean_fieldname(self):
        fieldname_value = self.cleaned_data.get('fieldname')
        # check if field is valid.
```